# Deduce argument types from templated callable type

Tags: c++, c++20, template-argument-deduction

This questions has been asked before on Stackoverflow, but all answers I found were pre C++ 20 ones that did not exactly give a solution to my problem. I'm hoping that things have evolved.

I have a function which gets some callable type (a lambda, a function pointer, a struct with a call operator) and I need to deduce the argument types of the object passed in to create a tuple of that types. I think of something like this piece of pseudocode

```cpp
template <class Callable>
void foo (Callable&& callable)
{
    using ArgsTuple = std::tuple<ArgumentTypesOfCallable...>; 
    
    // Do some fancy stuff with that tuple
}
```

I'm pretty sure that there must be some way of deducing these types with C++ 20, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: In general callables don't have a defined set of parameters. They could be using template parameters in function parameters and be callable with any set of argument types. Therefore it is usually not helpful to do this. And nothing really changed in C++20.

Comment: What's the expected result, if you pass an instance of `struct Foo{ void operator(int){} void operator(void*) {} };`?

Comment: `foo([](auto){ return 42; })`, now what?

Comment: Thanks @Barry, this example just made the problem totally clear. Didn't think of templated functions or lambdas with auto arguments

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need C++20 to do this, but you do need to separate out the arguments you're planning to call your function with if you want to do anything useful. Here's a simple (full) example that I think will do what you want, though I have no idea what you actually plan to do with the tuple you're making:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
    
template<typename Func, class... Args>
void DoUniqueCorrectly(Func&& fn, Args&&... args) 
{
  using ArgsTuple = std::tuple<Args...>;

  std::cout << "Getting ready to invoke\n";
  ArgsTuple tup(args...);
  if constexpr (std::tuple_size<ArgsTuple>{} > 0) {
      std::cout << "arg1 = " << std::get<0>(tup);
  }
  if constexpr (std::tuple_size<ArgsTuple>{} > 1) {
      std::cout << ", arg2 = " << std::get<1>(tup);
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
  std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void test(const char *arg1, int arg2)
{
    std::cout << "test called! arg1 = " << arg1 << ", arg2 = " << arg2 << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DoUniqueCorrectly(test, "hey!", 22);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Getting ready to invoke
> arg1 = hey!, arg2 = 22
> test called! arg1 = hey!, arg2 = 22
> ```

Try it yourself on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5GPq4GoWc)

The printing of tuple elements is placeholder, to do a proper generic iterator would take up a lot more space. You can find plenty of other questions on stack overflow that do that the "right" way.

**Edit:** As Ben Voigt points out, the elements of the `ArgsTuple` are going to have a type which is identical to the types passed to `DoUniqueCorrectly`, but not necessarily identical to the types of the functional call. A good way to illustrate this is to change the function signature of `test()` to:

```
void test(const std::string arg1, int arg2)
```

Since we invoked DoUniqueCorrectly with a `const char *`, the `ArgsTuple` will have type `<const char *, int>`, and this will be converted to `const std::string` on the invoke call. This may or may not be important in your particular application, but it's certainly important to be aware of if you adopt a solution like this.

Comment: Naturally this doesn't give the formal parameter types, but the types of the actual parameters.  There can be significant conversion taking place at the `std::invoke`.

Comment: Good point @BenVoigt, I'll make a note of this in the answer. Thanks!